# data key in useQuery

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, graphql

I was implementing GraphQl in React Native but I encountered a problem where while using useQuery for one exported object I did not have use the data key with the data but for the the other passed data I had to use it. Otherwise the data was undefined. Can someone please explain this working of useQuery?
I am attaching code snippet for better understanding.

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(COUNTRY_QUERY);// Not above

const { loading2, error2, data: data2 } = useQuery(COUNTRY_CODE_QUERY); //It had to be used here
```

This is the query that I typed:

```
export const COUNTRY_QUERY = gql`
  query CountryQuery {
    countries {
      name
    }
  }
`;

export const COUNTRY_CODE_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    country(code: "BR") {
      name
      capital
      code
      native
      emoji
      currency
    }
  }
`;
```

I have tried it with different parameters but it was no use.

Comment: Your first query has a name "CountryQuery" whereas your second one doesn't.